# Reduce image sequence frames

Tags: bash, zsh

So after exporting a video to a image sequence, I have ended up with way more images than I needed. I would like to trim this down. The images are named 1.png, up to 959.png. Is there a convenient way of doing this with a bash/zsh script? Something like removing every other image and renaming the next to keep the order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To delete file 1 5 9 13 17 ... with bash: `rm {1..959..4}.png`

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found somewhat of a solution.

```
#!/bin/zsh

c=0
cc=0
ext=".png"
for file in `ls | sort -V`
do
  let c=c+1;
  let cc=cc+1;
  if [ $c -eq 2 ]; then
    rm -f $file
    c=0
  else
    let cc=cc-1;
    new="$cc$ext"
    mv $file $new
  fi
done
```

This will list out all the files in the current directory and loop through them, deleting every other and renaming the next. Just be aware that this will rename the script file too, so you might want to create some logic to avoid that.

Comment: The easy way to avoid renaming/deleting the script by simply not placing it in the same directory. Better would be to run the loop only over the files you actually intend to touch: `for file in $(ls *.png | sort -V)` or better `for file in *.png(n)`.